# Controlling XML Serialization of a List<> derived class

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm converting a Dictionary object into a List<> derived class by means of the following two declarations:

```
[Serializable]
public class LogItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public LogItem(string key, string value)
    {
        Name = key; Value = value;
    }

    public LogItem() { }
}

public class SerializableDictionary : List<LogItem>
{
    public SerializableDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> table)
    {
        IDictionaryEnumerator index = table.GetEnumerator();
        while (index.MoveNext())
        {
            Put(index.Key.ToString(), index.Value.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void Put(string key, string value)
    {
        base.Add(new LogItem(key, value));
    }
}
```

I intend to serialize `SerializableDictionary` by means of the following code:

```
SerializableDictionary log = new SerializableDictionary(contents);
using (StringWriter xmlText = new StringWriter())
{
    XmlSerializer xmlFormat =
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializableDictionary), new XmlRootAttribute("Log"));
    xmlFormat.Serialize(xmlText, log);
}
```

Works fine, but I'm unable to change the XML formatting.

This XML document is intended to be sent to a xml database field and is not meant to be deserialized.

- I'd rather have both Name and Value
  formatted as attributes of the
  LogItem element.

However any attempts at using XMLAttribute have resulted in Reflection or compilation errors. I'm at loss as to what I can do to achieve this requirement. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can annotate them with  `XmlAttribute`:

```
[Serializable]
public class LogItem
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public LogItem(string key, string value)
    {
        Name = key; Value = value;
    }

    public LogItem() { }
}
```

This worked fine for me and produced the following XML (based on sample input):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Log xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <LogItem Name="foo" Value="bar" />
  <LogItem Name="asdf" Value="bcxcvxc" />
</Log>
```

Comment: Oh gosh! It did to me too. The Value property used to be declared as an 'object' before and that's when the above wasn't working. I had just changed it to string because I realized of the mistake, but never assumed that would change everything. Thank you so much, BrokenGlass

Answer (score 1):

There must be something else going on besides what you are showing. I am able to compile and execute the above code both with and without the XmlAttribute attribute applied to the Name and Value properties.

```
[XmlAttribute]
public string Name { get; set; }
[XmlAttribute]
public string Value { get; set; }
```

Comment: Yes, there was StellarEleven. I actually had the Value property in LogItem declared as an 'object' and that's when I was having the error and XmlAttribute wasn't working. However I actually intended to have it as a string and made that change a few minutes before posting. I never tested since because it wouldn't occur to me this simple change would make such a difference.